# Tkinter can't open mutiple photos

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I am trying to open multiple tinker images. But when the first image loads up it stops the rest of the code from running please help.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()

canvas=Canvas(root,width=420,height=560)
image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\Users\photo.jpg"))
root.geometry("420x560+0+0")

canvas.create_image(0,0, image= image, anchor=NW)
canvas.pack()
root.overrideredirect(1)

root = Tk()

canvas=Canvas(root,width=420,height=560)
image2= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:\Users\photo.jpg"))
root.geometry("420x560+77+77")

canvas.create_image(0,0, image= image2, anchor=NW)
canvas.pack()
root.overrideredirect(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Only use one ``Tk()`` instance in your project.The other window should use ``Toplevel()``

Comment: ``Image.open(r"path")``.You have used ``\`` in it.

Comment: Whatever,it has many errors in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I can not run this code in my computer,but just see your code.

You have used `root = Tk()` in line 4.
Then you also use `root = Tk()` in line 14.

And when you use `mainloop()` in your code.it will `mainloop` the `Tk()` instance in line 14.Because the first `Tk()` has been covered.

There are two solutions:

1. If you want to show two windows at the same time.Use `.after` in the first `Tk()` instance and call a function to show another picture in a `Toplevel()` instance(Don't use 
   many `Tk()` instance at the same time.It maybe will bring some bugs).
2. Or you want to show it in the same window,Just use `.grid()`(or others) to place them in the place of the window where you want.

A easy example for `.after()` to show more than two windows:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

def ShowAnotherWin(i):
    win = Toplevel()
    win.title('Show')
    image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(i))
    canvas=Canvas(win,width=420,height=560)
    canvas.create_image(0,0, image= image, anchor=NW)
    canvas.pack()
    win.mainloop()

YourImageList = ['C:/Users/photo.jpg','C:/Users/photo.jpg']
root = Tk()
for i in YourImageList:
    root.after(0,lambda :ShowAnotherWin(i))
root.title('First')
image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"C:/Users/photo.jpg"))
canvas=Canvas(root,width=420,height=560)
canvas.create_image(0,0, image= image, anchor=NW)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

`YourImageList` is the Image list that you want to show.You should put your path in it.

Comment: Okay thanks, but how do you implement .after can you please show me how you would implement it in my code thnaks.

Comment: @HarrieSwanepoel Here are two windows ``root`` and ``win``,use `ImageTk` to put pictures in the windows.

Comment: Like this ???? don't think i am doing it right I have updated my photo